# C#/WPF/Avalonia - On button click change text

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui

I am using Avalonia 0.9.2.

I am very new to it and I am unable to change text when button is pressed.

Here is my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ReadyForWar_Launcher.ViewModels;assembly=ReadyForWar_Launcher"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="ReadyForWar_Launcher.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="ReadyForWar_Launcher">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Update the Text" Command="{Binding UpdateText}" CommandParameter="Hello World!"></Button>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </StackPanel>


</Window>
```

Here is my `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Message = "Welcome to Avalonia!";
    public void UpdateText(object text)
    {
        Message = (string)text;
    }
}
```

When I click the Button `Update the Text` nothing happens? Why is that? I want to update the text of `Message` to be `Hello world!` but nothing happens.

Why is that, where is my error ?

Comment: Does `UpdateText` method is fired when you click button?

Comment: I don't know how to test that.

Comment: Just put breakpoint to entrance of method

Comment: Looks like it is going inside but not changing the text...

Comment: I didn't work with Avalonia, but I would guess that Text has to be a property, maybe with some change notification

Comment: What does `ViewModelBase` look like?  Does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Doesn't  avalonia binding work like wpf? You need public properties to bind. That's not a property. And you need to raise propertychanged.

Comment: @haldo can you form a complete answer?

Comment: No, I can't.  You've not shown ViewModelBase or clarified whether it implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Does the answer below not answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [page](https://avaloniaui.net/docs/binding/change-notifications):

```
using ReactiveUI;

public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string caption;

    public string Caption
    {
        get => caption;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref caption, value);
    }
}
```

This means that for the change to be reflected in the UI, the porperty needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Read up on that.

Comment: Hello can you please make a complete answer with example of how it should work ?